# ui-router dynamic template path

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router 0.2.8. I'm wanting to load a template based on device width. I can get the device width without issue, set it in the scope etc but I can figure out how to bind it to $stateParams. I have the scope variable in another controller which can be accessed the state's controller it's just not available to the state itself. I've tried the templateProvider but that is only returning me a string. What else can I try in order for this to work?

```
.state('list', {
abstract: true,
url: "/list",
templateUrl: 'views/'+$stateParams.somevalue+'/page.html',
    controller: "myCtrl"
 })
  .state('list.first', {
url: "/first",
templateUrl: "views/first.html"
  })
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access to state params in the `$stateChangeStart` event. You can also dynamically update the `templateUrl` there as well.

So perhaps your code might look something like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
        if (toState.name === 'list') {
          toState.templateUrl = 'views/'+toParams.somevalue+'/page.html';
        }
    });
}
```

You might also want to take a look at the [onEnter callback](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#onenter-and-onexit-callbacks) supported by ui.router. I have not used this before but it might be neater than putting your template generating code into the `$stateChangeStart` event.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it breaks the idea of UI-Router's state configuration. Instead of maintaining states all in one Config block, you're splitting up configuration in multiple locations which will only cause headaches down the road. See Dipesh Kc's answer for a more configurable and easily maintainable solution.

Answer (score 90):

You might be looking for dynamic template name based on the state params

```
 $stateProvider.state('contacts', {
   templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
     return '/partials/contacts.' + $stateParams.filterBy + '.html';
   }
 })
```

See the docs for more information
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates

Comment: While being the "correct" solution, using only the injected `$stateParams` might no be enough in some cases. Thus @biofractal 's answer might be the more general case soluton

Comment: Is it also possible to set templateUrl to an injectable function inside an angular directive?  I'm guessing it isn't...?

Comment: I agree with @RicardoPedroni.  I had to use the other answer to set an isMobile variable on toParams so that the variable is available in templateUrl functions via $stateParams.  That way I can have different templates for mobile, desktop, etc.

Comment: This is great but there is one drawback here and that is what If I want to make http request before rendering the view and based on the result returned from that what if i want to change the view. I can't access http in templateUrl function

Answer (score 0):

This reference here was great for me figuring out how to do dynamic templates in angular, but I'd like to update with my own solution.

- Solution 1 based on Dipesh Kc's (this works great for redefining parent templateUrl for abstract states) Notice I used toParams instead of $stateParams:

  ```
  // custom parent template
  .state('template', {
      abstract: true,
      url: "/tm/:tmfolder/:tmview",
      templateUrl: function (toParams) {
          return 'views/' + toParams.tmfolder + '/' + toParams.tmview + '.html';
      },
  })
  .state('template.contacts', {
      url: "/contacts/:folder/:view",
      templateUrl: function (toParams) {
          return 'views/' + toParams.older + '/' + toParams.view + '.html';
      },
  })
  ```
- Solution 2 based on biofractal's (there is no way to update a parent templateUrl using this method):

  ```
  .state('contact', {
      url: "/contact/:folder/:view"
  })

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
      var customStates = ["contact"]
      for (var i = 0; i < customStates.length; i++) {
          if (toState.name.indexOf(customStates[i]) != -1) {
              toState.templateUrl = 'views/' + toParams.folder + '/' + toParams.view + '.html';
              break;
          }
      }
  });
  ```