# Use different route / state for each subdomain or domain name, in AngularJS / ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, subdomain

My Angular application has many different domain names and subdomains pointed to it. I would like each one to take a different state in my routing. How do I do this?

Let me give an example:

```
domainname1.com
subdomain.domainname1.com
sub2.domainname1.com 

domain2.com
sub1.domain2.com
```

ALL point to my application root. 
My routes / states might look something like this:

```
    $stateProvider
            .state('Dom1Sub0', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/s0View.html',
                controller: 'domain1Controller as user'
            })
            .state('Dom1Sub1', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/s1View.html',
                controller: 'domain1Controller as user'
            })
            .state('Dom1Sub2', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/s2View.html',
                controller: 'domainController as user'
            })

            .state('Dom2Sub0', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/s0View.html',
                controller: 'domain2Controller as user'
            })
            .state('Dom1Sub1', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/s1View.html',
                controller: 'domain2Controller as user'
            })
```

How can I add an "if" statement for each state, based on the domain or subdomain?

> SO FAR:

I have found some code here to extract the subdomain :

```
app.factory('subdomain', ['$location', function ($location) { 
        var host = $location.host();
    if (host.indexOf('.') < 0) 
        return null;
    else
        return host.split('.')[0];
}]);
```

so i can do the same for the domain:

```
    app.factory('domain', ['$location', function ($location) {
var host = $location.host();
if (host.indexOf('.') < 0) 
    return host.split('.')[0];
else
    return host.split('.')[1];
}]);
```

and add them to my controller :

```
    app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'subdomain', function ($scope, subdomain) {
 // use subdomain same as any other variable
}]);
```

But how do I change state based on the value of domain and  / or subdomain?

Thanks

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but instead of having different states, you might have just one state and then define some parameters like `domain` and `subdomain` for the state.  Then you can pick the appropriate template using a template function, as shown [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24261127/398606). You can do something similar with controllers, using [controllerProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#controller-controllerprovider).

Comment: This was my initial thinking. However, i ran into problems when I wanted to use state params as part of the url. For example, a full url might be :  subdomain.domainname1.com/username1234 - this allows the multi-tenant application to have any number of user-defined pages. The state for this would be " url: '/:usernameParam', " ... would this solution still work for this case? I'll try it later...

Comment: On the surface I think it could work. UI Router is so powerful, but when I set out to do something ambitious like this it always takes a bit of of effort to get it right :)

Comment: @Leon if you found the solution then please post the answer, I am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: Nope. This is the one functionality I cannot seem to fix using angular / UI router. It seems possible but I just can't make it work