# Template Provider Doesn't Fire $Scope Logic

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular ui-router and need to show a different template for a given state based on a variable in the parent (`body`) scope. But when I add this `$scope.data` conditional it doesn't fire. I don't even get the `console.log()` or any url change. :(

```
$stateProvider.state('map1', {
    url: "/content/sectionI",
    templateProvider: function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
        console.log("Wowie!",$scope.data);
        if($scope.data.Section_I_Part_1_Complete == "0")
        {
        return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/contentMore',
        params: {
          request: "Section_I_Part_1_Complete",
          part: "1"
        }
      }).then(function successCallback(html) {
        return html.data;
      });
      }
else
    {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/contentMore',
        params: {
          request: "Section_I_Unlocked",
          part: "map"
        }
      }).then(function successCallback(html) {
        return html.data;
      });
    }
       },
     controller: function($scope) {
           $scope.activeSection.activeSection = "notNone";
        }
  })
```

How do I do it so that I can get the template to return based on the value of a variable in the parent scope?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to define a state with dynamic templateUrl. You can achieve that by changing templateUrl value on `$stateChangeStart`. See related SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512238/ui-router-dynamic-template-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a service to store the data and inject that service.

```
templateProvider: function(myDataService) {

  var part = myDataService.Section_I_Part_1_Complete == "0" ? 1 : 'map';
  return $http.get('http://example.com/contentMore', {
    params: {
      request: "Section_I_Part_1_Complete",
      part: part
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
}
```