# popup modal for login to go some hiding page with resolve state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal, resolve

**The requirement is:** When I type URL for some hiding page, page should not render at the moment, first one modal should popup for login, if login is successful then the hiding page should be render on the screen.

**My Idea is:** To use resolve in state, as I am using ui-router for my application.

But I am not getting how I can open the modal while requesting for the some page, and simultaneously how I can prevent it as well.

```
.state('deviceManagement', {
        url: "/deviceManagement",
        templateUrl: "partials/settings/deviceManagement.html",
        controller: "deviceManagementCtrl",
        resolve: {
            check: function(engineerPageFactory){
                engineerPageFactory.loginEngineer();
            }
        }
    })
```

My idea is like I will open modal in factory I called from resolve.

```
app.factory('engineerModalFactory', function($modal){
    return {
        loginEngineer: function($modal){
            $modal.open({
                 templateUrl: "engineerModal.html"
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Something like this. Please guide me correct way. How I can make it possible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can achieve it without using resolve for details check my answer

Comment: I can tell you what I did to cope with this very same situation. When the user logs in, some `$rootScope` data gets defined (e.g. user's details). The controller of the hidden page checks if those variables are defined and, if not, set a forwarding page into the $rootScope, routes to the index.html who also checks parameters and, if needed, present the login dialogue and, upon successful login, route to the hidden page. Not sure this is the best and most elegant approach, but it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for answer both of you!
@TheMechanic can you please tell me how i can achieve it with or without resolve?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you should not need resolve

create a service `checkUserService` which will return promise.

while your controller load call `checkUserService` method to identify user is logged in or not?

In promise you will get the response true or false.

if user is not logged in redirect it to other state for example:

`$state.go('login')`

and in loginController you can open model

Comment: I don't want to check, i want to open modal to login, whenever hiding page is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

you Should Take a toogle variable  inside a modal  and open a page on true and false condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just call dynamic template URL with same state.

```
 $stateProvider.state('deviceManagement', {
   templateUrl: function (MyAuthService){

      MyAuthService
         .checkLogin()
         .then(function(loggedInFlag){
            if(loggedInFlag ===true){
               return 'partials/settings/deviceManagement.html';
            }
            else {
               return 'partials/auth/loginModal.html';
            }

         })
   }
 })
```

For more info, check this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24261127/2837412)