# Angular ui-router hidden parameter to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I have the following ui-router state for one of my tabs:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('systems', {
          url: '/Tabs/System',
          templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
              return ('/Tabs/Systems/IndexNoLayout') + (typeof $stateParams.CustomerName === 'undefined' ? '' : '/' + $stateParams.CustomerName);
          },
          params: { CustomerName: '' },
          controller: 'systemCtrl'
      });
```

A link to that tab:

```
<a ui-sref="systems({CustomerName: 'dummyCustomer'})">
    Save state
</a>
```

And an MVC controller with an optional parameter:

```
public ActionResult IndexNoLayout(string CustomerName){...}
```

This parameter is then used in my MVC View using Razor.
The code above works.
But I would like to have my templateUrl definition as follows:

```
templateUrl: '/Tabs/Systems/IndexNoLayout'
```

This way I could easily delete the $templateCache on $stateChangeStart for this Angular view:

```
$templateCache.remove(fromState.templateUrl);
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This SO post helped me solve my problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512238/ui-router-dynamic-template-path)

Thus my solution:

```
  $stateProvider
      .state('systems', {
          url: '/Tabs/System',             
          templateUrl:'/Tabs/Systems/IndexNoLayout',
          params: { CustomerName: '' },
          controller: 'systemCtrl'              
      });
```

In my $stateChangeStart:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {            

        if (toState.name == "systems") {
            toState.templateUrl = ('/Tabs/Systems/IndexNoLayout' + (typeof toParams.CustomerName === 'undefined' ? '' : '/' + toParams.CustomerName));
        }

        $templateCache.remove(toState.templateUrl); ...});
```