# Passing paramter to URL using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep seeing examples on this but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I load an item and its content into `ng-view`. When I refresh the page, it disappears. I have passed a parameter to the URL of the state and I am lost what to do next.

People have talked about `$stateParams` which I can log from my controller and I can see that item with `id: 3` has been selected.

How do I keep the view populated with this item even on refresh? An example with my code would be greatly appreciated.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$routeProvider',  function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $routeProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise('/patents');

    $stateProvider
        .state("patents", {
            url: "/patents",
            templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/list-patents.htm",
            controller: "patentListCtrl",
        })
        .state("patents.item", {
            url: "/:id",
            templateUrl: function() {
              //THIS IS WHERE I AM NOT SURE HOW TO PASS THE URL THE ID
            },
            controller: "patentItemCtrl"
        })
}]);

app.controller('patentItemCtrl', ['$scope', 'patentTabService','$stateParams', '$state', '$routeParams', function($scope, patentTabFactory, $stateParams, $routeParams){

      console.log($stateParams.id)

}])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24261127/1457231

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to to retrieve the required data by making a call your data service and then assign to your view. In your case call patentTabService to get patent with the id and then load that patent object into your view. For example, note I am assuming you already have some way to get a patent by id in your service:

```js
app.controller('patentItemCtrl', ['$scope', 'patentTabService','$stateParams', '$state', '$routeParams', function($scope, patentTabFactory, $stateParams, $routeParams){
      $scope.patent = {};
      if (Number.isInteger($stateParams.id) ){
        $scope.patent = patentTabFactory.getPatent($stateParams.id);
      }
      
      console.log($stateParams.id)
}])
```