# Change templateUrl in view states on the fly in angular UI router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is is possible to change and reload the template of an state after being defined in config?

I want to allow the user on click to change the template of the current page, my idea is to broadcast an event that changes the templateUrl defined in the stateProvider, but no idea how to do it.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            cache: false,
            templateUrl: '/_/admin/templates/login.html',
            controller: 'login'
        });
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? There are such many workarounds like: `ng-if` `ng-include` for different html templates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ui-router dynamic template path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512238/ui-router-dynamic-template-path)

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create template URL from `$stateParams` like this.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            cache: false,
            templateUrl: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
              return 'your template';
            }],
            controller: 'login'
        });
});
```